# Unable to locate an option to create API key in Google Maps Enterprise portal

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to implement Google maps Embed API in SugarCRM. We have Google Maps Enterprise License and are provided with Client ID and Crypto key. As per the documentation, Embed API requires API key to be provided in request URL.

Please suggest where can I find an option to create API key from Google Maps Enterprise portal (http://www.google.com/enterprise/portal)?

Also, is Embed API free and does not require license?

Answer (score 0):

To create an API key for Embed API, navigate to [Google Developer Console.](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cloudconsole&passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.developers.google.com%2F&ltmpl=cloudconsole)

Go to "APIs & auth" -> APIs. In the search box, search for Embed and enable the API. Embed API is free and does not require license. It has 2,000,000 QPD quota.